# Kubernetes Deployments and Init Containers

Tags: kubernetes

I [learned recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233242/kubernetes-cluster-and-phoenix-automate-mix-ecto-migrate/44233465#44233465) that Kubernetes has a feature called [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). Awesome, because I can use this feature to wait for my postgres service and create/migrate the database before my web application service runs.

However, it appears that Init Containers can only be configured in a Pod yaml file. Is there a way I can do this via a Deployment yaml file? Or do I have to choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid confusion, ill answer your specific question. i agree with oswin that you may want to consider another method.

Yes, you can use init containers with a deployment. this is an example using the old style (pre 1.6) but it should work

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: 'nginx'
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 'nginx'

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: 'nginx'
      annotations:
        pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
            {
                "name": "install",
                "image": "busybox",
                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                "command": ["wget", "-O", "/application/index.html", "http://kubernetes.io/index.html"],
                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                      "name": "application",
                      "mountPath": "/application"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: 'application'
          emptyDir: {}

      containers:

      - name: webserver
        image: 'nginx'
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: 'application'
            mountPath: '/application'
```

Comment: As far as the question is concerned, you hit the nail on the head. Turns out that my cluster on GCE was still on 1.5. Your code would work, but I decided to upgrade to 1.6 instead. Then I was able to put `initContainers` in the Deployment yaml

Comment: glad it was helpful.

Comment: @JamStar would the init container execute once per deployment or once per pod?

Comment: @JavierHolguera have you ever found out if the init container is once per deployment or once per pod? Also is there a way to do it once per deployment?

Comment: init containers are before the real pods start so one per deployment.

Comment: In addition to what @JamStar said : if you have replicas set to a number higher than 1 you'll have the same numbers of init-containers as replicas. (But if you have replicas set to one and many containers declared in the template section, you'll have only one instance of your init-container)

Comment: @ChristopherRivera behaviour that I see is actually one initContainer run per pod start. Killing the pod and thus forcing deployment to recreate it triggers new init run.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use readiness probes instead of init containers for this use case. Check out this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) and a [blog](https://medium.com/spire-labs/utilizing-kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-to-automatically-recover-from-failure-2fe0314f2b2e). Also note that a deployment will not send traffic to a pod that is not reported ready - If that was your worry.

This is a well known pattern and a readiness probe in the web server would simply check the DB endpoint / data availability before reporting ready. This is a simple solution as opposed to the complexity of an extra init container and has the advantage of detecting DB outages correctly as well.

Comment: I think init containers are not relevant in any way to readiness probes. Init containers run until completion and successful exit before the application containers will start, and as per docs - k8s will wait for all init containers to succeed before starting the application containers. Init containers are designed to run finite one-off pod startup tasks, while readiness probes are for reporting the status of indefinitely running applications. And not all bootstrap tasks are appropriate to put in the application containers.

Comment: @alexykot I did not attempt to elaborate about the relation between init containers and readiness probes, but pointing the OP to a solution that may be appropriate to his original problem, based on the little information we have. This is a well known pattern and a readiness probe in the web server would simply check the DB availability before reporting ready. This is a simple solution as opposed to the complexity of an extra init container. (added this to the answer)

Comment: The OPs original problem was not only to wait for DB availability, but also to "create/migrate the database", which is a separate specific task outside of readiness probe's scope.

Comment: @alexykot In this standard scenario the DB container would do the required initialization before being ready and the webservice would not be ready until the db endpoint is ready - Simple but effective and the best separation of concerns in my opinion. Avoids the complexity on the infrastructure level.

Comment: DB may not be in a container, e.g. it can be a managed cloud instance. And I'm not sure how can DB container know what schema structure the application requires.

Comment: @alexykot if the DB is not part of the cluster then the OP question here does not apply and all you have to do is make the web-server-readiness dependent on DB endpoint availability. In order to perform specific schema initialization/migration/etc for a DB in a container you would set up the initialization as part of the init script and build it into the container and / or load a configuration from the environment (e.g. configuration file from object storage, another service, etc).

Comment: As far as I can see OPs question was about `initContainers` in the first place. I don't see how the database placement (in-cluster or elsewhere) is relevant to how you run migrations, migrations are application logic, not DB server logic. So I think the init containers are relevant regardless.
You can place migrations logic into the application startup or into initContainer in the same pod, I think both are reasonable and intended-purpose approaches.