# Replacement for initContainers for older kubernetes version

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes v1.5.2 and I wanted to use a statefulSet that contains the `initContainer` spec. When trying to create the statefulSet I got the message:

```
error validating "my-statefulSet.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field initContainers for v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I believe that this spec is not available for the version that I am using. So is there anything similar for my version that I can use or is my only option to move the config under the `containers` spec? When I move the spec over to `containers` I get the issue of the persistentVolumes not being ready on time for the pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Kubernetes Deployments and Init Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256184/kubernetes-deployments-and-init-containers) you have an example of init containers defined via beta annotation